# SplayTrees and a Dictionary

Tags: java, dictionary

I'm use a splaytree class as the data storage for the "dictionary".

I have the following to deal with Integers, Objects, etc.:

```
public class SplayTree<T extends Comparable<? super T>>
```

And I also have the following:

```
public class Entry<T> {
    public Entry(T word, T def){}
    ...
}
```

Which is what I'm using to add a word entry and its definition

But when I try to run some test data, for Ex:

```
SplayTree<Entry> tree = new SplayTree<Entry>();
tree.insert(new Entry("test", "test"));
```

I get the following error:

> Bound mismatch: The type Entry is not
>   a valid substitute for the bounded
>   parameter > of the type SplayTree

Any idea to what I should do to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

You didn't make class Entry implement Comparable.

```
public class Entry<T> implements Comparable<T> {
    // ...
    public int compareTo(final T t) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that need to have a method `compareTo` instead of `compare`?

Comment: ooh right thanks - that's the sort of mistake I make 10000 times a day :-)